# XMLHttpRequest - как получить ответ из php-файла?

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

Есть php-файл:

```
$links = array(
    "leads" => "111", 
    "orders" => "222"
);
$address = $_GET["address"];
echo $links[$address];
```

Делаю к нему запрос, но ответа не получаю (нужно получить "111"):

```
var address = "leads";
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "file.php?address="+address, true);
request.send(null);
alert(request.responseText);
```

Comment: а что по вашему обозначает третий параметр метода `open` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Включить асинхронный тип запроса:

```
request.open("GET", "file.php?address="+address);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status != 200) {
    alert(`Error ${request.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`);
  } else {
    // request.response - загруженный ответ
    alert(`Done, got ${request.response.length} bytes`);
  }
};
```